# MySQL on duplicate key on a non-unique field

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a table containing all sort of parameters.
The structure of the table is : **id, object_id, param_name, param_value**

The following code works, but it appends results instead of updating them.
The fact is that I can't use [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) because my fields are non-uniques (except for **id** of course)

```
INSERT INTO `params_table` (`object_id`, `param_name`, `param_value`)
SELECT
A.id AS my_object_id,
'XYZ' AS my_param_name,
IF(TMP.abc IS NULL,0,1) AS my_param_value
FROM
ref_table AS A
LEFT JOIN tmp_table AS TMP ON TMP.abc = A.abc
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE `param_value` = IF(TMP.abc IS NULL,0,1);
```

Comment: Are you allowed to create new indexes?

Comment: Yes, and I already have an index on object_id

Comment: If you want to update a record instead of inserting a new one it means it is somehow unique, maybe you need a unique key on a pair of columns (object_id,param_name) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3180913/90527)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause does not only work on the primary key:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a
>   UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE
>   of the old row is performed

So unless I'm missing something obvious you simply need to create a unique index on the column combination you want to make unique:

```
ALTER TABLE params_table
ADD UNIQUE unique_object_param(object_id,param_name);
```

Comment: you would not want to update column being a part of unique key, if it is really key that is needed it is (object_id,param_name)

Comment: in my case it's more like `ADD UNIQUE foo(object_id,param_name);`
That should do the trick, thank you

Comment: @HurrDurr - I've edited my answer to match your comment. For the records :)